# CMake for Halide Hexagon failed while successfully compiled using g++

Tags: cmake, halide

I am writing CMake file for the following command:

```
g++ --std=c++11 -DLOG2VLEN=7 -DRUN=1 -DASSEMBLY=1 -DBITCODE=1 -I 
/home/user/Qualcomm/HALIDE_Tools/2.2.06/Halide/include -fno-rtti -O3 -g 
halide_gaussian_hexagon_generate.cpp /home/user/Qualcomm/HALIDE_Tools/2.2.06/Halide/tools/GenGen.cpp 
-L/home/user/Qualcomm/HALIDE_Tools/2.2.06/Halide/lib -lHalide -o 
bin/halide_gaussian_hexagon_generate -ldl -lpthread -lz -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
```

Above compiling works fine but when I wrote it into CMake I got a bunch of error. I am attaching my CMake file here:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(hexagon_polyblur)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(HEXAGON_DIR $ENV{HALIDE_ROOT})

set(
    HEXAGON_FILES_GAUSSIAN
    halide_gaussian_hexagon_generate.cpp
    ${HEXAGON_DIR}/tools/GenGen.cpp # we must include GenGen to compile the generator
)

set(HEXAGON_GEN_GAUSSIAN ${PROJECT_NAME}_hexagon_generate_gaussian)
add_executable(${HEXAGON_GEN_GAUSSIAN} ${HEXAGON_FILES_GAUSSIAN})
target_include_directories(
        ${HEXAGON_GEN_GAUSSIAN} PRIVATE
        ${HEXAGON_DIR}/include
        ${HEXAGON_DIR}/tools
)
target_link_libraries(${HEXAGON_GEN_GAUSSIAN} ${HEXAGON_DIR}/lib/libHalide.so dl pthread z)
target_compile_options(${HEXAGON_GEN_GAUSSIAN} PUBLIC -fno-rtti)
# target_compile_definitions(${HVX_GEN_GAUSSIAN} PRIVATE LOG2VLEN=7 RUN=1 ASSEMBLY=1 BITCODE=1 _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
```

In CMake, I am using /usr/bin/g++ and /usr/bin/gcc (g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0), which are the same compiler I used for the command line. The ${HEXAGON_DIR} is /home/user/Qualcomm/HALIDE_Tools/2.2.06/Halide. I am not sure why I the CMkae failed here. Part of the error message is shown below:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/hexagon_polyblur_hexagon_generate_gaussian.dir  /halide_gaussian_hexagon_generate.cpp.o: in function `Halide::Internal::check_introspection(void const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)':
halide_gaussian_hexagon_generate.cpp:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `Halide::Internal::Introspection::get_source_location[abi:cxx11]()'
/usr/bin/ld: halide_gaussian_hexagon_generate.cpp:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `Halide::Internal::Introspection::get_variable_name(void const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/hexagon_polyblur_hexagon_generate_gaussian.dir/halide_gaussian_hexagon_generate.cpp.o: in function `HalideIntrospectionCanary::(anonymous namespace)::TestCompilationUnit::TestCompilationUnit()':
...
```

Also, when I switch to my original working halide lib that is not for hexagon development, this CMake works. I am not sure whether or not I have a wrong setup in CMake. Any help or suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: In your original command line you specify `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`, but in `CMakeLists.txt` the corresponding `target_compile_definitions` is commented out.

Comment: Have you considered using a more recent version of Halide? Since version 10, we've had good (and constantly improving!) CMake support via `find_package`. You should really just do that and link to the `Halide::Generator` imported target.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a more recent version of Halide? Since version 10, we've had good (and constantly improving!) CMake support via `find_package`.

This should be all you need:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(example)

find_package(Halide REQUIRED)

add_executable(hexagon_gen_gaussian halide_gaussian_hexagon_generate.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hexagon_gen_gaussian PRIVATE Halide::Generator)
```

Then you can call [`add_halide_library`](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/README_cmake.md#add_halide_library) to run the generator.

Here's a link to our CMake docs for reference: https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/README_cmake.md

You should also look at our example applications (most of them have CMake builds): https://github.com/halide/Halide/tree/master/apps

Feel free to ask any follow-up questions on our GitHub Discussions since I wrote our CMake build/package code.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> -L/home/user/Qualcomm/HALIDE_Tools/2.2.06/Halide/lib -lHalide
> ```

Translates literally to:

```
target_link_directories(.... ${THEDIR}/lib)
target_link_libraries(... Halide)
```

or better:

```
add_library(halide SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET halide PROPERTY
         IMPORTED_LOCATION ${THEDIR}/lib/libHalide.so)  # or maybe find_library
# 
target_link_libraries(... halide) # I wish there would be "target_link_targets"
```

---

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

Better:

```
set_target_properties(testproject PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED on # maybe also
    CXX_EXTENSIONS off
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I tried both but still get the same error. Here is more information. The error appeared when executing `/usr/bin/c++ CMakeFiles/gaussian5x5_generator.dir/gaussian5x5_generator.cpp.o CMakeFiles/gaussian5x5_generator.dir/home/user/Qualcomm/HALIDE_Tools/2.2.06/Halide/tools/GenGen.cpp.o -o bin/gaussian5x5_generator  -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/Qualcomm/HALIDE_Tools/2.2.06/Halide/lib /home/user/Qualcomm/HALIDE_Tools/2.2.06/Halide/lib/libHalide.so -ldl -lpthread -lz`. I think all lib are corrected linked.  Also try /usr/bin/g++ but sill the same error.

Comment: Re: "I wish there would be 'target_link_targets'"... there (sort of) is! Imported (and alias) targets may have `::` in the name and `target_link_libraries` will always interpret a library with `::` as a target name (and error out if the target is missing).

Comment: `Imported (and alias)` Yea, but creating an alias for each library is no fun. You could write `target_link_targets` where you check `if (TARGET` for each argument, but static libraries can have circular depdendencies, so it does not work. Is it possible to check if they are targets are at the end of configuration stage? That would be nice.

Comment: Well in your code above you don't need to create an alias. You can just call the imported target `unofficial::halide` or something.

Comment: My understanding was that the target checks in `target_link_libraries` were in fact done at generation time, but if not I'm pretty sure you could defer it via `$<TARGET_NAME:...>`